# Anonymous Contributions & Contributors in Open Source Projects

Tags: open-source

Having witnessed in various open source projects, in which I have been involved, several more or less significant totally anonymous contributions, I am wondering what could be the possible rationale behind such anonymous contributions?

Occasionally, there are contributors who quite obviously prefer to remain completely anonymous - i.e. by just posting to a mailing list using an obvious nick name for months (whereas everyone else would use their real name), or sometimes even by submitting completely anonymous patches to trackers on sourceforge, where there wasn't even the slightest comment about the origins/authors, usually just a license header or a header stating that the code in question were to be released into the public domain.

Often, the code in question was obviously written by fairly competent programmers/developers or even software engineers, who presumably do code for a living.

I am wondering:

- What's the motivation behind such contributions?
- Have you previously witnessed such and similar instances in open source projects?
- Have you, yourself possibly contributed to an open source project in such a fashion?
- If so, why?
- Can you provide any other insight into this?

After having read [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455221/releasing-open-source-without-the-permission-of-your-employer/646208#646208) question here on SO, and also after having read two related discussions (at [slashdot](http://developers.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=02/03/21/0139244) and [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?lastnode_id=26179&node_id=153046)) about potential work-contract related issues when contributing to open source projects, I am wondering whether some contributors could possibly prefer to remain completely anonymous due to their contract requirements, in order to avoid potential legal issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of several reasons:

1. some people simply value privacy - I know that I usually do not post on most forums with my name - SO is the exception for me (and even here it was only after a couple months);
2. many programmers work at places where part of the employment agreement is that any code you write (whether on company time or not) belongs to the employer.  Whether or not these agreements might apply to the submissions, the programmer may be wanting to avoid 'tainting' the submission or may want to avoid going through the bureaucratic hoops to get permission from the employer;
3. the submitter may not want to be contacted for support;
4. the submitter may not be particularly proud of the code (rightly or wrongly);

Answer (score 4):

I own two reasonably popular open source projects. I have accepted such contributions. The rationale is simple. They are using the project and want a problem resolved or feature implements sooner rather than later.

The contribution benefits them!

Comment: That doesn't answer none's question since could apply equally well to any other contribution. It does not point out why someone would contribute anonymously. Please rethink your answer.

Comment: Choosing anonymity means that they've decided to forgo the reputation that is one of the rewards for valued contributors, so their motivations are likely more focused on the benefits of *the patch*...

Comment: @moocha: Your dumb, of course it answers the question. What does it matter what project the contribution is made to. Any persons actions are driven by their motivations, the motive here is contributing something that "benefits them".

Comment: +1, I think this is actually a pretty good answer, some folks are probably simply being egoists (i.e. scratching their own itch), while appreciating their privacy, even when contributing ;-)
On the other hand, even anonymous contributions may satify legal requirements (i.e. to contribute code back, when commercially used/released). So they may be interested in complying, while not appreciating any publicity.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason I can think of is they have some sort of contractual binding preventing them from contributing openly, such as working for a large software corporation that views open source projects as a potential liability.  Or they just don't want to be bothered with people asking for more information or more support.